# php code is not executing instead get downloaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

my api is returning php code instead of executing it on ubuntu 18, php7.1, xampp7.1 server. i try lot of solutions available on SO. php is installed in my system.
output of `php -v`

```
PHP 7.1.33-12+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2020 07:22:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33-12+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

some of the solutions i tried:

1. installed `libapache2-mod-php7.1`.
2. add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php` in `.htaccess` file
3. `a2query -m php7.1`
4. set default php to 7.1 `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1`
5. try creating a `test.php` file in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and add php code

   ```
   <?php phpInfo(); ?>
   ```

   it's working fine. but, when i move this file to api(`/opt/lampp/htdocs/api`) directory, it's not executing instead  it gets downloaded
6. comment out below part in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.1.conf

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

api url  `POST http://localhost/api/api`
directory structure `/opt/lampp/htdocs/api/api.php`
api.php code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
if(file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../**.php")) {
    require __DIR__ . "/../**.php";
} else {
    require __DIR__ . "/**.php";
}
$app->run();
```

i also try reinstalling xampp, php but nothing works.

Comment: side note: Need to upgrade from php 7.1. It was EOL last year.

Comment: my team is using php 7.1, so i have to stick with it

Comment: LOL, your conf is so weird in a way (don't ask me pls)

Comment: there are no conf file. which file you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file should be placed in the directory which is main. So, if you want the .htaccess to work in /var/www/html/anything, then the .htaccess file should be placed in /var/www/html, if you want the .htaccess to work in /web/apps/anything, then the .htaccess file should be placed in /web/apps. Therfore, the .htaccess file shound be placed either in the directory or the parent directory (which is /var/www for /var/www/html, you understand this right?) to make this work.

So, if you want to put your .htaccess file anywhere you want, (it should be inside the web root), and it should use the `RewriteBase /` to make it work for /var/www/html if it is placed in /var/www/html/something.

### All the directory paths mentioned here are for example. Don't use the same directories unless you are already using / or if you want to use them. the above configurations will work which ever directory you are on.

Comment: i have `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/api` directory. after adding `RewriteBase /` in `.htaccess` it's not working

Comment: When I'm accessing my api routes, it send php code instead of json data as response.( Its working on other team members system)

Comment: i solved it by removing removing PHP version in `.htaccess` file.  
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php` to `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: @GouriShankar Glad you did. Also, upto you (don't take this as rude), [upvote/downvote/flag/share/edit/accept]!